# local DNS with dnsmasq not working for client

Tags: networking, dns, raspberrypi, dhcp, dnsmasq

I'm trying to setup my raspberry Pi, running with Ubuntu server 20.04, as a wireless router so I can create a local network behind my raspberry pi.

I'm using `hostapd` to create a Wifi Access Point and `dnsmasq` to have a local DNS and DHCP server. The DHCP server seems to work fine: when a client connect (my macbook for instance), it get an IP in the range defined by the DHCP.

But I have issue with the DNS server for local domain name defined in the `/etc/hosts`. It works fine on the Rasp Pi but not for the client: when I try `nslookup gw.wlan` from the client shell I got:

```
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

** server can't find gw.wlan: NXDOMAIN
```

`gw.wlan` is defined in the `/etc/hosts` of the rasp Pi (see below)

Any idea why dnsmask doesn't read the `/etc/hosts` file ?

It works fine for internet domain name. If I run `ping google.fr` in the client shell it pings google just fine. Only local domain name are not resolved.

---

Here are my configuration files:

- `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
# Listening interface
interface=wlan0

# Pool of IP addresses served via DHCP
dhcp-range=192.168.4.2,192.168.4.20,255.255.255.0,24h

# Local wireless DNS domain
domain=wlan

# Alias for this router
address=/gw.wlan/192.168.4.1

# Fix ip for a client
dhcp-host=98:01:a7:95:63:13,192.168.4.2

# Route
dhcp-option=3,192.168.4.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.4.1
localise-queries
local=/wlan/
```

- `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.4.1/24
```

- `/etc/hosts` :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost ubuntu
192.168.4.1 gw.wlan
192.168.4.2 jjmac.wlan

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

- `/etc/resolv.conf` :

```
domain wlan
search wlan
nameserver 192.168.4.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

- `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` :

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

Comment: Eliminate the last 2 `nameserver` lines. Those servers will know nothing about `.wlan`. Also, in `dnsmasq.conf`, there's an inconsistency between `dhcp-address=` and `listen=`. Why an IPv6 address only in one?

Comment: @waltinator thx for your reply, the last two nameserver (8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1) are there so I can have internet access from the server. I don't see the inconsistency in the addresses, where do see a `dhcp-address` ? maybe the line `dhcp-host=98:01:a7:95:63:13,192.168.4.2` is confusing but it actually define the ip of the client with the defined mac address, not the ip of the host

Comment: I also edit my initial post. I added ip masquerade so now internet domain name are well resolved, only local domain name are not